# printing value of two variables using awk in specific column of a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I do not want to just print value of variables  using awk.  Actually i want to print value of variables in specific columns of a file.  I already tried the link "How to use shell variables in an awk script"

Below is my requirement.

I have two variables and i want to print the values of these variables in specific columns.  I have tried below to print the value of variables but it is not giving the desired result.

```
awk '$2 = $2 FS "$test" infile
```

From link "How to use shell variables in an awk script" i can understand how to 
print value of variables by my requirement is to print the values of two 
variables in specific columns. For example i have two variables and i need to 
print the value of both variables in column 3 and 4.

Below is the example.

**infile**

```
2017/03/31-465       17:00:22 01:20:18 Completed                        63249705
2017/03/30-490       17:00:19 00:15:17 Completed                        12205725
2017/03/29-502       17:00:19 00:15:12 Completed                        12108819
2017/03/28-496       17:00:20 00:14:58 Completed                        12060389
2017/03/27-487       17:00:24 00:15:29 Completed                        11990615
2017/03/26-76        17:00:22 32:05:10 Completed                        62974897
2017/03/24-465       17:00:22 01:24:26 Completed                        62974897
2017/03/23-494       17:00:16 00:14:30 Completed                        11970151
2017/03/22-489       17:00:19 00:14:49 Completed                        11923575
2017/03/21-472       17:00:19 00:14:52 Completed                        11878081
2017/03/20-463       17:00:20 02:21:25 Aborted                                 0
2017/03/12-78        17:00:19 32:05:16 Completed                        62466091
```

I have below 2 variables and i want to print the values of both variables in 
column say 3 and 4.

variables : - test and test2

I tried using below code . But it print `$test` instead of values of variables 
test. When i gone through link "How to use shell variables in an awk script" and 
able to print the values of variable but not able to print in specific columns 
of file.

```
awk '$3 = $3 FS "$test"' infile
```

Comment: Pls add example input and desired output. I cannot understand what do you want by reading your question.... I hope others could.

Comment: I have added a example in my question.

Comment: Use: `awk -v var="$test" '{$3 = $3 FS var} 1'`

Comment: You say you read the duplicate question yet are still incorrectly using the shell variable in awk.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the value of shell variable in awk, you should do in this way:

```
awk -v value="$test" '$3=$3 FS value ....' input
```

If you used `$test` directly in awk, awk think that it references a column, the column index is in (awk variable) `test`, default it is `0`, which would be `$0`(the whole line).